# Is "There is 300 tonnes of water" correct in terms of grammar?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

Can I write: "There is 300 tonnes of water"?

We can definitely write: "There are 300 bottles of water" but I am not sure if this is the case with tonnes, dollars, pounds .etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must differ with the other answerer. I believe a singular verb is idiomatically much more appropriate here.

I will quote from Quirk's *Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (1985 edition, pp. 757, 758).

> The principle of notional concord accounts for the common use of a singular with subjects that are plural noun phrases of quantity or measure. The entity expressed by the noun phrase is viewed as a single unit:
>
> - Ten dollars *is* all I have left. ['That amount is ...']
> - Fifteen years *represents* a long period of his life. ['That period is ...']
> - Two miles *is* as far as they can walk. ['That distance is ...']
> - Two thirds of the area *is* under water. ['That area is ...']
>
> *Cf: Sixty people means a huge party.* ['That number of people means ...']

Please also note, in contrast with the other answer, that *ton* and *tonne* are not synonyms. The latter word means "metric ton."

Comment: I disagree, slightly. Notional concord is messy. An example of the OP's intuition paired with your answer that is *more idiomatic*: "Bob: There are 300 tonnes of feathers over there. Betty: Wow, 300 tonnes of feathers is a big pile."

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to say about "tons" (plural) not about "one ton" (single), you should use "are":

(Maybe best way to use the word "tons" instead "tonnes" because this is more frequent form)

Below you can see result of ngram search for "tons", "tones" and "tonnes":

[image]
[image]
[image]